# Selecting data from two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two database tables,
1st is the `TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS` where all products information are stored.

```
store_id, product_id, product_name, product_description, product_price
```

The 2nd table is the `TABLE_STORES` where all stores information are stored.

```
store_id, store_name, store_country, store_tags, store_description
```

I have a search form where user can search for products where the store is on the selected country.
Lets say, I want to search for cotton shirts where stores are located only on the US.

Now, In a mysql query, How can i select `product_id, product_name, product_description, product_price` in `TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS` where

`store_id`(in TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS) is the `store_id`(in TABLE_STORES) is the selected `store_country`. I hope I explained it clearer.

How to accomplish it or is there a way to accomplish it better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by joining both tables
Try this

```
SELECT p.*
FROM TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS p
INNER JOIN TABLE_STORES s ON s.store_id = p.store_id
WHERE s.store_country = 1
```

Assuming 1 is the selected country

Comment: Thank you. Thats what im looking for.